# GNU CGI using C++

Tags: c++, cgi, gnu

I am writing CGI programs in C++ (on Windows). I am trying to use cookies but i am getting compile time errors. I used GNU library from  http://www.gnu.org/software/cgicc/
I extracted zip file and placed folder in my include folder in Dev C++ directory. I can also use Visual studio (Visual C++). But i am getting same error. Cgicc namespace is not recognizing. Please help me. If you know other software i will use it. Please do tell me, where to and how to add libraries.

Errors are:

```
"C:\Users\USI\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp" -o "C:\Users\USI\Desktop\Untitled1.exe"    -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2\include"  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2\backward"  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2\mingw32"  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2"  -I"C:\Dev-Cpp\include"   -L"C:\Dev-Cpp\lib" 
C:\Users\USI\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp:8:27: cgicc/CgiDefs.h: No such file or directory
C:\Users\USI\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp:9:26: cgicc/Cgicc.h: No such file or directory
C:\Users\USI\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp:10:41: cgicc-3.0.1/HTTPHTMLHeader.h: No such file or directory
C:\Users\USI\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp:11:37: cgicc-3.0.1/HTMLClasses.h: No such file or directory
C:\Users\USI\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp:14: error: expected namespace-name before ';' token
C:\Users\USI\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp:14: error: `<type error>' is not a namespace
C:\Users\USI\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp: In function `int main()':
C:\Users\USI\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp:21: error: `Cgicc' undeclared (first use this function)
C:\Users\USI\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp:21: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in.)
C:\Users\USI\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp:21: error: expected `;' before "cgi"
C:\Users\USI\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp:22: error: `const_cookie_iterator' undeclared (first use this function)
C:\Users\USI\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp:22: error: expected `;' before "cci"

C:\Users\USI\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp:37: error: expected primary-expression before "const"
C:\Users\USI\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp:37: error: expected `;' before "const"
C:\Users\USI\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp:39: error: `cci' undeclared (first use this function)
C:\Users\USI\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp:39: error: `env' undeclared (first use this function)

Execution terminated


#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>  
#include <string>  
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h> 

#include <cgicc/CgiDefs.h>
#include <cgicc/Cgicc.h> 
#include <cgicc/HTTPHTMLHeader.h> 
#include <cgicc/HTMLClasses.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cgicc;



int main ()
{

     Cgicc cgi;
   const_cookie_iterator cci;
    cout << "Set-Cookie:guessNo=2;\r\n";

   cout << "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n";


    cout << "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n";
   cout << "<html>\n";
   cout << "<head>\n";
   cout << "<title>Cookies in CGI</title>\n";
   cout << "</head>\n";
   cout << "<body>\n";
   cout << "<table border = \"0\" cellspacing = \"2\">";

   // get environment variables
   const CgiEnvironment& env = cgi.getEnvironment();

   for( cci = env.getCookieList().begin();
        cci != env.getCookieList().end(); 
        ++cci )
   {
      cout << "<tr><td>" << cci->getName() << "</td><td>";
      cout << cci->getValue();                                 
      cout << "</td></tr>\n";
   }
   cout << "</table><\n";

   cout << "<br/>\n";
   cout << "</body>\n";
   cout << "</html>\n";

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that
1)CgiDefs.h Cgicc.h, HTTPHTMLHeader.h and HTMLClasses.h are all in the cgicc directory
2)cgicc directory is itself in a directory listed in "Additional include directories" in Visual Studio C++ compiler settings, or the DevC++ equivalent of those.

Your errors indicate that the compiler simply does not find those .h files.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you haven't configure path to header files of cgicc. Make sure that directories cgicc and cgicc-3.0.1 are in one of the directories that are set with -I flag.

Comment: Right click on your project.
Check "Additional include directories" under Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++ in Visual Studio

Comment: there is a option to include additional libraries from computer. I added GNU gicc directory  but errors are not resolving